# Ionic EmailComposer Android Image attachments Base64 not funkcionary

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I read my photos from the device, which I then display on the screen and send as an attachment in the email. The problem is when I add an attachment it throws me out of android.

Attached to me. show me shows thanks to base64 but it doesn't attach itself as an attachment and completely throws me out of android.

My code is

```
captureImage= () =>{
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 70,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    }
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then (imageData =>{
     
    this.base64Image  = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, err => {
      console.log ('Image error: ', err)
    });
  }


  
  sendEmail(){
    let email = {
      to: 'mnemeth83@gmail.com',
      cc:'office@webshopassist.sk',
      attachments: [
        this.base64Image 
      ],
      subject: 'Moja fotka',
      body:'Poprosím pozrite sa nato!<br><br>',
      isHtml: true
    };
    this.emailComposer.open(email);
  }
}
```

In Android manifest have i this

```
 <queries>
    <intent>

      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
      <data android:scheme="*" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
```

Whats the problem? Please help my.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with email composer, due to newer Android versions.

Try this:

- Install 6.1.1 gradle version and in Android Studio > Gradle Settings point the Gradle to installation folder.
- Add `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip` to `gradle-wrapper.properties`.
- Keep your added query inside of AndroidManifest.xml
- Finally set targetSdkVersion = 30 in `variables.gradle`.

Comment: Hi,thank i make all . Write the error

Comment: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
Required by:
    project :
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File

Comment: Have you downloaded the gradle version and did the steps?

Comment: Yes, first steps download the 6.1.1 gradle and how i need to set this gradle? in settings gradle.the unzipped gridle folder 6.1.1 set?

Comment: When you open Android Studio, on the (far) right there should be a tab 'Gradle' that you can expand, then look for the wrench icon - click it and select Gradle Settings. When the dialog opens, look for the line 'Use gradle from:' and choose 'specified location' then point it to the folder where you unpacked your downloaded gradle version.

Comment: Yes I make this and write this :(

Comment: But have you added the distributionUrl as in next step? Your error does sound like you didn't.

Comment: Yes I added the distribution Url

Comment: Check what you have in android > build.gradle under 'dependencies' for gradle classpath

Comment: Yes I have dependencies

Comment: my grdale completely fell apart